# Children returned from FunctionComponent breaks Parent rendering logic

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, antd

I created a FunctionComponent that should return conditionally the children that are envolved by it.

```
<Tabs defaultActiveKey='1' type='card' activeKey={'1'}>
    <TabPane tab='Tab title' key='1'>
        <p>Tab title</p>
    </TabPane>
    <WrapperComponent>
        <TabPane tab='Tab title' key='2'>
            <p> Tab title 2 </p>
        </TabPane>
    </WrapperComponent>
</Tabs>


const WrapperComponent: React.FC<Props> = ({children}) => {
    if(true)
        return (children)
    else
        return <></>
}
```

When the wrapper returns the children element, the UI breaks and don't render properly.
Tabs are imported from [antd](https://ant.design/components/tabs/).

The result from the page render:
[image]

The same occurs on any element that are render whit some logic from antd UI library.

**EDIT**

I'm looking to find a way to render the child element based on some conditional, and after rendering it, force the parent element to "refresh" the UI, thus redoing the logic of creating the UI library component.

*My goal in all of this is to create a component to validate that the logged in user has permission to render the object. With this, I seek to avoid the repetition of logic variables in the TSX file and obtain a more reusable and componentizable project architecture.*

Comment: `<WrapperComponent />` "returns" something like `{ type: WrapperComponent, props: { children: { type: TabPane, props: {...} } } }`, not `{ type: TabPane, props: {...} }`. It does not return its children, it renders them.

Comment: nice @Thomas, the solution can be it, but any ideas to how i can set the return to the children type dynamically?

Comment: Yes, do *not* use a wrapper component. What's `WrapperComponent` supposed to do?

Comment: This WrapperComponent were supposed to be a permission handler, that validates the user permissions located on localstorage, and if user has permissions should render the children element. I removed this logic to simplify the code.

Comment: If it's just a matter of render or not, can you use `{ hasPermission("foo") && <TabPane ...}`.  It's certainly the easiest solution in this case.

Comment: It works, but my goal is to avoid logical statements as "validate permission" directly into the presentation file (tsx). Anyway, i appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are trying to modularize the code. Move access control logic to a separate class, say `ACL`. This class doesn't need to be an UI component. Simple class will do.
In your UI component use class methods to determine if you want to show features or not.
Codepen [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-antd-4-18-5-forked-t425w?file=/index.js:558-568)
**ACL.js**

```js
// access controll managment
var ACL = (function () {
  var role = "guest";
  var getRole = function () {
    return role;
  };

  var init = function () {
    //read local storage/ cookies and get role
    role = "admin";
  };

  var hasAccessTo = function (page, feature) {
    //do the checking
    return role === "admin";
  };

  // call this after login
  init();

  return {
    init: init,
    getRole: getRole,
    hasAccessTo: hasAccessTo
  };
})();

export default ACL;
```

In your UI component it can be used like this:

```js
import ACL from "./ACL";


// filter based on role
function filter() {
  if (ACL.hasAccessTo("tabsPage", "secretTab")) {
    return (
      <TabPane tab="Secret" key="2">
        The access code is: ██████
      </TabPane>
    );
  }
}

const Demo = () => (
  <Tabs defaultActiveKey="1">
    <TabPane tab="Info" key="1">
      Genral info
    </TabPane>
     
    /* you can write a separate function to do the filtering */
    {filter()}

    /* OR use expression like this */
    {ACL.hasAccessTo("tabsPage", "secretTab") && 
      <TabPane tab="Secret 2" key="3">
        secret 2: some secret
      </TabPane> }
  </Tabs>
```

---

Your current `WrapperComponent` doesn't work because wrapped tabs are not getting processed properly. For example, id is `rc-tabs-0-tab-null` the key is missing.

Comment: It seems that your solution works like a charm to modularize the code and avoid the business rules into the UI page. I will something similar to the second approach, that feels more reusable in pages that will call the ACL many times. Thank you! Just a doubt, if my initial approach using UI component worked, it would have any disadvantage compare to your approach using class?

Comment: If you want to implement this on multiple pages then you'll need to implement the "WrapperComponent" for each page. A lot of extra code, so hard to maintain. To avoid this if you make the "WrapperComponent" generic which will handle access control for all the pages then you'll need to pass extra parameters like which page, and which feature on that page. Which is what I've done in the ACL class. The ACL class puts all access control logic in one place, Finally, access control is a pure business logic and doesn't involve actual rendering so it doesn't make sense to have it in a UI component.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is create a list of tabs and filter-based permission/roles.

```
const tabs = [
  {
    key: "1",
    tab: "Tab title",
    content: <p>Tab title</p>,
    permissions: ["admin", "user"],
  },
  {
    key: "2",
    tab: "Tab title 2",
    content: <p> Tab title 2 </p>,
    permissions: ["admin"],
  },
];

const WrapperComponent = ({ tabs, role }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {tabs.map(
        (tab) =>
          tab.permissions.include(role) ? (
            <TabPane tab={tab.tab} key={tab.key}>
              {tab.content}
            </TabPane>
          ): null
      )}
    </>
  );
};

<Tabs defaultActiveKey="1" type="card" activeKey={"1"}>
  <WrapperComponent tabs={tabs} role="admin" />
</Tabs>;
```